# How can I style the items in the hamburger menu in a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar, hamburger-menu

I created a responsive navbar with Bootstrap4.
When the screen is large, there are 2 buttons. When the screen is small there is a hamburger menu.

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]

How can I style the element in the navbar so that when they are in the hamburger menu don't look like buttons anymore?

Thanks!

This is my code:

````
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MyJobBoard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 float-right text-right">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link post-a-job-button pull-right">Create a profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-3 pull-right">Sign In</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-3 pull-right">Post a Job</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav> ```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujYIG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE4ib.png
````

Comment: Will your nav-items for Sign In and Post a Job open a modal for the user to do either task or will they take the user to another page? If clicking on the buttons does something (like opening a modal), then buttons is the right choice, but if clicking on the buttons brings the user to a different page, then they should be structured as links. You can use button styling on a link.

Comment: Hi @RichDeBourke, thanks for your reply. Clicking on the buttons the user will see a form. The problem is that the style in the hamburger menu is off and I don't know how to make it look nicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to structure all of your nav-items as links so that on smaller screens, you will have the normal Bootstrap slide-down menu, and then to custom button classes that get applied for larger displays.

If your sign-in and post-a-job forms are on a separate page, then you can use a straight link to the other page, but if you’re using modals to show the forms, then you’ll need to use JavaScript to open the modals.

I’ve disabled the post-a-job button in the example below so you can see how to disable a button so someone who isn’t signed in can’t post a job.

```js
$('a[href$="#signInModal"]').on("click", function() {
    $("#signInModal").modal('show');
});

$('a[href$="#postJobModal"]').on("click", function() {
    $("#postJobModal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .btn-md {
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #212529;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            padding: .375rem .75rem;
            font-size: 1rem;
            line-height: 1.5;
            border-radius: .25rem;
            transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
        }

        .btn-primary-md {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #007bff;
            border-color: #007bff;
        }

        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.disabled {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        }

        .btn-md:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <!-- Container wrapper -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MyJobBoard</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 float-right text-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link post-a-job-button mr-md-3" href="#">Create a profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-md btn-primary-md mr-md-3 text-white-md" href="#signInModal" role="button" style="width: 6.125rem">Sign In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-md btn-primary-md mr-md-3 text-white-md disabled" href="#postJobModal" role="button" style="width: 6.125rem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Post a Job</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="signInModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="signInModalLabel">Sign In</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Form for signing in (or registering) goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="postJobModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="postJobModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="postJobModalLabel">Post a job</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Form for posting a job</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <!-- Container wrapper -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Navbar brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MyJobBoard</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 float-right text-right">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link post-a-job-button mr-md-3" href="#">Create a profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-md btn-primary-md mr-md-3 text-white-md" href="#signInModal" role="button" style="width: 6.125rem">Sign In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-md btn-primary-md mr-md-3 text-white-md disabled" href="#postJobModal" role="button" style="width: 6.125rem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Post a Job</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="signInModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="signInModalLabel">Sign In</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Form for signing in (or registering) goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="postJobModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="postJobModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="postJobModalLabel">Post a job</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Form for posting a job</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: I’m glad it worked for you. If my answer satisfies your question, please check the Accept icon (the checkmark) so others knows the question is answered, and if it the answer is what you needed, it’s nice to click the up-arrow next to the question to signify it’s a helpful answer